# Generics in Java - Creating a Generic Method

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I would like to try to create a generic method that takes an array, the length of the array, and an element that returns the position of the element in the array. I'm new to Java and I'm trying to learn Generics.

I can't seem to get the position of the element, and I don't even know if I'm doing this right, any advice would be great.

```
public class GenericsProj {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] intArray = {1, 2, 3, 4};
        String[] stringArray = {"one", "two", "three", "four"};

        routineArray(intArray, intArray.length, 4);
        routineArray(stringArray, stringArray.length, "four");
    }


    public static <T> void routineArray(T[] array, T length, T element) {
        System.out.println("Inside the array: " + Arrays.toString(array));
        
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] == element) {
                pos = array[i];
                System.out.println(pos);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not make the `length` of type `T`, the length is ALWAYS an `int`, same goes for the position, will always be an `int`.

Comment: And apart from that you be encountering https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: You don't need the `length` parameter or `pos` anyways (and you haven't declared `pos`). If you want the index of the element, print `i` instead of `array[i]`. Also, use `.equals` instead of `==` when comparing strings and other objects.

Comment: omg, you all are life savers, thank you!!
now I'm going to try to create a greater than method that will compare two objects, AHH.

Answer (score -1):

Now `routineArray` prints for each occurrence the element from your input if the element is in the array list, if you want return the position of the element you need to do `pos = i` instead of `pos = array[i]`. In this case, you can change the return type of the method from T to int.